# caonnot import file <***.ovpn> as it is already in the global or local config directory when connect openvpn client

Tags: vpn, openvpn

My os is Windows10.

When I import .ovpn files, I got this error message.

"caonnot import file "C:\Program Files\OpenVPN\config\client.ovpn" as it is already in the global or local config directory"

I tried reinstalling openvpn, deleted the folder "C:\Program Files\OpenVPN", "C:\gpqls\OpenVPN", and tried again, but same error.

How to solve it?

Answer (score 2):

The error occurred because you have .ovpn files in your global or local config directory.

It can be solved in the following ways.
OpenVPN stores the configuration in 2 places:

Global Directory: C:\Program Files\OpenVPN\config

User's Directory: C:\Users[YOUR_USERNAME]\OpenVPN\config

So, firstly delete the .ovpn configuration file from both folders. Then, copy the VPN configuration file to "C:\Program Files\OpenVPN\config" and rerun the OpenVPN

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).